# Recommended sequence for directives in htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Thanks in advance for comments and suggestions.

My wordpress site was hacked so I deleted it and started from scratch beginning with a proper htaccess document. As I was configuring the htaccess directives, I closely monitored the server error logs and added various directives to redirect spambot from the old directory as well as added deny from ip ranges  and user agents. I then added various directives like nosniff, prevent the common attacks on files and sql, prevent hotlinking etc.

The htaccess doc is now fairly large but thankfully hasn't slowed the site yet.

I've search the net and read over docs related to htaccess but nearly all are tips&trick code examples.

Q: Is there a Recommended sequence for the various directives in htaccess design or are the htaccess doc directives digested by apache without regard for sequence of requests?

I realize this is a newbie question so feel free to flame.

Comment: If you really are an admin and have access to the httpd conf files, you shouldn't need a .htaccess. Start by not needing it and get it right.

Comment: httpd conf file changes require an Apache restart. I'm a client on a shared server. If the admins actually cared about clients they'd kill the RBLs at the router.

Comment: Serverfault is for admins ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people who use `.htaccess` files and ask about it on ServerFault should not be using `.htaccess`  in the first place as that is an end-user solution never intended for administrators:

> You should **avoid using .htaccess files completely** if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using `.htaccess` files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.
>   **Source:** [Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/htaccess.html) << **read this!**

But apparently most people who publish their configurations appear to be [cargo cult programmers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) keen on copying .htaccess files blindly without understanding the reasons.

A second important section of the manual is on [how directives are merged](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#mergin): understanding that will save you from grief.

Comment: Thanks for the flame and great links! As the admins on my shared server could care less about clients, its up to me so I'm headed back to the reading desk ; )

Comment: @testbench not a flame per se but my pet peeve... Nothing wrong with shared hosting (started my career at a hosting company) but that is a mass market product and once you outgrow that and performance starts to matter it is time to consider more bespoke solutions (and pay for that)...

Comment: I encouraged flame which typically gets to the heart of the issues. I fully understand your pet peeve... as a server administrator yet question the corp. policy which constricts your knowledge. example: why aren't RBLS and known threats rejected at the router to benefit all server clients? The sign-up criteria is simple. They sign-up for a regional market and the router denies all to the server. Why isn't any Hosting service doing the obvious?

Comment: They sign-up for a regional market and the router denies all to the server. s/b They sign-up for a regional market and the router denies all but their market to the server.